# How to add custom font to TinyMCE FontSelect in WP Admin or filter the fonts available

Tags: tinymce, fonts

So I know how to add more default buttons to the TinyMCE Visual Editor using the following:
`//Add TinyMCE built in buttons
    add_filter("mce_buttons_2", "add_more_buttons");
    function add_more_buttons($buttons) {
        $buttons[] = 'charmap';
        $buttons[] = 'fontselect';
        $buttons[] = 'fontsizeselect';
        return $buttons;
    }`

I want to be able to put a client's custom fonts that they want in that font select. I know how to add a custom button using php and jquery, but I was hoping there was a way to filter out these fonts.

Anyone heard of anything like this?